# How to calculate co-occurence in python for huge data

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I wanted to calculate the co-occurrence such that it can be used as an edge for the construction of a graph. I have a column skill that consists of the list of skills for each id in the dataset. Now I wanted to calculate cooccurrence and use it as an edge.the data format is

```
skill

Product Management,RPM,Progress 4GL,IP,CAMEL,Prince2 Foundation,Continuous Integration,GSM(HLR,MSC),Programming,SS7,INAP,ClearCase,SS7 protocol,Software Development,Shell Scripting,GPRS(SGSN,GGSN),MySQL,VOIP,Linux,Agile,SIP,Diameter,Test,Oracle,Software
User Experience,Interaction Design,3D rendering,Event,Team,Graphic Design,Engineering,User Experience Design,Sales,3D Modeling,Product Marketing,Employee Training,business plan,3D,Business Development,Creative Problem Solving,Product Design,renewable energy,Electronics,news paper,Project Management,Product Development,Social Enterprise
```

the above is the skills list of two ids in the dataset.

Now I want my output to be in the format of 3 columns which is the source, target, and weight count, and in the next step I can use them for the graph construction.

```
      Source_elt  Target_elt WeightCount
```

Can anyone share your insights that would be helpful. My endpoint is that using this weight count I will go further for community detection.

I amusing the following code for the co-occurrence calculation.

```
document =nested_list

#unique job titles
fnc_names = unique_jobtitle

# Get a list of all of the combinations you have
expanded = [tuple(itertools.combinations(d, 2)) for d in document]
expanded = itertools.chain(*expanded)

# Sort the combinations so that A,B and B,A are treated the same
expanded = [tuple(sorted(d)) for d in expanded]

# count the combinations
c = Counter(expanded)


#initialize NxN matrix with zeros
table =np.zeros((len(fnc_names),len(fnc_names)), dtype=int)

for i, v1 in enumerate(fnc_names):
    for j, v2 in enumerate(fnc_names[i:]):        
        j = j + i 
        table[i, j] = c[v1, v2]
        table[j, i] = c[v1, v2]


df_cooccMatrix = pd.DataFrame(table, index=fnc_names, columns=fnc_names)
df_cooccMatrix.head()
```

and later for the weight count

```
#Assign count as f edge

weight_cout = df_cooccMatrix.stack()
weight_cout = pd.DataFrame(weight_cout.rename_axis(('Source_elt', 'Target_elt')).reset_index(name='WeightCount'))
#weight_cout.sort_values(by=['WeightCount'], inplace=True, ascending=False)
#weight_cout.head(10)
```

But when I am calculating weight count I am getting the memory issue

```
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 6.25 GiB for an array with shape (1678704784,) and data type int32
```

so can anyone help me in solving the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are the columns in the output dependent on the input column `skill`? It's not clear how co-occurrence is defined here.

Comment: It's not related to the input column. I added the output for the format purpose. Please don't go with the data inside the columns,I want my final output in the format of 3 columns i.e source target and its weight count

Comment: What measure do you use to calculate the weight count?

Comment: Present I am trying to use co-occurrence count to calculate the weight count. ```#Assign count as f edge

weight_cout = df_cooccMatrix.stack()
weight_cout = pd.DataFrame(weight_cout.rename_axis(('Source_elt', 'Target_elt')).reset_index(name='WeightCount'))``` this is the code I am trying to do it

Comment: df_cooccMatrix is the co-occurrence matrix for the skill data set.But when I am trying to calculate the weight count I am getting memory issue because of heavy data

Comment: Can you add this information into the question? It will help others to solve the problem.